# How to integrate job queue in node js?

Tags: node.js, express

In my node js application I want to integrate job queue. Let me explain, for example let's say I want to place an order and the item is for $50 but price goes up and down so I want to buy it once it's $45 so I placed an order which should be executed once the item comes to $45. In this process what is gonna happen is a job should run which should check the price every hour for 5 days, once the price matches then it should automatically execute the order and if the price didn't come to expected price then after 5 days it should refund the amount. I want jobs to be concurrent because in this there will not be only one user doing it. Please help in how to achieve this functionality

I searched about libraries like bull etc. But I can't find what I am looking for in this library

Comment: What does this mean ***"I want jobs to be concurrent because in this there will not be only one user doing it."***?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to execute multiple jobs at a time this is what I mean